# Managing a database connection with a global, global name disappears

Tags: python, global-variables, kodi

```
class MyAddon(pyxbmct.AddonDialogWindow):
    def __init__(self, title=''):
        super(MyAddon, self).__init__(title)
        self.mysql_connect()
        self.populate()

    def populate(self):
        categories = self.read_data()

    def read_data(self):
        query = ("SELECT category FROM test")
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        categories = cursor.execute(query)
        return categories

    def mysql_connect(self):
        global connection
        try:
            connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config).cursor()
        except mysql.connector.Error as err:
            if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
                xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, Bad user name of password)')
            elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
                xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, Database does not exist)')
            else:
                xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, {0})'.format(err))
```

I'm developing a Python add-on for Kodi. I get a `Global name 'connection' is not defined` error when trying to use a global variable for the database connection. I cannot read the global variable connection from the read_data function. I'm sure this is not a forward reference problem because I tested it that way.

The purpose of using a global variable for the connection is to reuse the connection in all the functions without creating a new connection every time.

Comment: Please include the *full traceback*.

Comment: Note that your code, as written, will *replace* the global `connection` each time you create an instance; you are not re-using anything here. You could use a class attribute instead of a global, by the way; `connection = None` at the class level, then `if not MyAddon.connection: MyAddon.connection = ...`; any attempts to *read* `self.connection` will find the shared class attribute.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be that Kodi does something funky with namespaces or your instances are pickled; when unpickled the global will be gone. Another problem with a global like this is that the connection might be lost at some point.

I'd restructure the code to have a method that returns a connection, and use that in all methods that require a connection. Make the connection method a classmethod and *allow for the connection to be gone*:

```
class MyAddonConnectionFailed(Exception): pass

def read_data(self):
    query = ("SELECT category FROM test")
    try:
        conn = self.connect()
    except MyAddonConnectionFailed:
        # connection failed; error message already displayed
        return []
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    categories = cursor.execute(query)
    return categories

_connection = None

@classmethod
def connect(cls):
    if cls._connection and cls._connection.open:
        return cls._connection

    try:
        cls._connection = mysql.connector.connect(**config).cursor()
        return cls._connection
    except mysql.connector.Error as err:
        if err.errno == errorcode.ER_ACCESS_DENIED_ERROR:
            xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, Bad user name of password)')
        elif err.errno == errorcode.ER_BAD_DB_ERROR:
            xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, Database does not exist)')
        else:
            xbmc.executebuiltin('Notification(Error!, {0})'.format(err))
     raise MyAddonConnectionFailed
```

I'm raising an exception in the `connect` classmethod; you'll need to decide how you want to handle the case where your database is misconfigured or can't connect. Displaying an error message is not enough. You *could* still call `self.connect()` from the `__init__` method to signal this problem early of course.

Comment: Thanks for the pattern suggestion. Can you please explain to a Python novice what the following lien does?
cursor = .cursor()

Comment: @Prashan: it'll produce an error because in editing I forgot to add the `conn` reference in front.. Sorry about that!

Comment: One last thing, I notice that the _connection = None is in the class level indentation. Did you mean to declare _connection as a global variable?

Comment: @Prashan: *no*, I did not. It is a class attribute. That's why I use `cls._connection` to reference it, from a `classmethod`.